# jquery .on('click', func) function not doing its job

Tags: jquery

How to create the issue:

1. click on existing trigger links - something happens (pass)
2. click on the "add trigger" button, which appends a new trigger link w/ same class
3. click on the newly created link, and it does not do the same thing as the 1st 2 links that existed from the start (fail)

Here is my example -: http://jsbin.com/equjig/3/edit

I thought the `.on('click', func)` function was good for adding events to current elements in the dom, but also for future elements that get added to the dom?

Here is my current javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#out").append("clicked<br/>");
  });

  $("#b1").on('click', function() {
    $("#p1").append("<a href='#' class='link'>new trigger</a>");
  });
```

here is the HTML

```
<button type="button" id="b1">add trigger</button>
  <p id="p1">
    <a href="#" class="link">trigger 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">trigger 2</a>
  </p>
  <div id="out"></div>
```

Note - im using jQuery 1.7

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, apparently nobody knows that jQuery 1.7 deprecates live. No more live answers!

Comment: @mrtsherman Or nobody felt it was reasonable to go to jsbin, check the jQuery version OP was using, and differentiate it from the three other versions also loaded. My guess is quite a few people know, but tend to rely on more-complete questions--which I believe is reasonable. Questions should include versions, and the code, particularly when it's this short.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ - I thought it was pretty clear. `On` did not even exist prior to 1.7 so he had to be using it. He provides the code he used `.on('click', func)`

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ i agree with you - if the code was within the question then less incorrect answers would have been added .... but mrtsherman is correct - `on` was already being used ... albeit incorrectly !

Comment: @mrtsherman I'm glad you did. IMO questions should be complete; we'll need to agree to disagree on that.

Comment: @All question updated for clarity ...

Comment: @DaveNewton - I included a link to a demo which has all the code in it.  I thought that would suffice.

Comment: @IanDavis no probs ... but remember that you caused all this fuss :-) lol and that in future you need to add the import bits of code and detail to your questions ....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are almost there with on ...

working example : http://jsbin.com/equjig/6/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#p1').on('click','.link', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#out").append("clicked<br/>");
    });
});
```

This will work - you should select a parent div of the `.link` elements (i have used `$('#p1')` here, like in your jsbin)

Answer (score 4):

`.on()` can also behave like `.delegate()` which is used like this:

```
//#p1 is the context and .link is what will be bound to as long as the .link element is a descendant of #p1
$('#p1').on('click', '.link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#out").append("clicked<br/>");
});
```

Here's documentation for `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: +1 - so many wrong answers its hard to find the correct ones to +!

Answer (score 4):

According to the api docs for [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the signature `.on('click', func)` replicates `.bind`'s behaviors - that is to say, it binds the listener to each and every *existing* element in the collection.

To get `.delegate` behaviors - that is, to bind to each and every event that originates from a specific kind of (child) element, include a selector:

```
$("parent-selector").on('click', 'your-selector', func)
```

Comment: @Ian Davis - of course, you'll need to make sure you are using 1.7 - `on` doesn't exist in earlier versions of jQuery.

Comment: +1 - nice answer. In OP's case something like this would work - `$("#p1").on('click', '.link', function(e)`

Comment: He is .... check out the jquery hes using -> /*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.on()` from version 1.7, and it also somewhat replaces the old `.live()` except in how you provide the syntax.

Using `.on()` you can delegate the event to any parent element like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.link',function() {
    // handler for all present and future .link elements inside the body
});
```

This way, it will also work for future elements that are added inside the body that has the className '`link`'.

I made a small modification to your lint that works the way you expect: http://jsbin.com/adepam. And here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document.body).on('click', '.link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#out").append("clicked<br/>");
  });
  $("#b1").on('click', function() {
    $("#p1").append("<a href='#' class='link'>new trigger</a>");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` event applied only to the elements that already exist. You need to use  `.live` function.

Answer (score -2):

Change the .on() to .live()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#out").append("clicked<br/>");
  });

  $("#b1").on('click', function() {
    $("#p1").append("<a href='#' class='link'>new trigger</a>");
  });
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7.